# Differentiability of piecewise function

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)= x+b$ when $x≤1$ and $f(x)= ax^2$ when $x > 1$, what are all values of $a$ and $b$ where $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$?

Please explain. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1) The function **must** be continuous at $\;x=1$, so

$$1+b=\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=a\implies a-b=1$$

2) Both one-sided differentials must be equal, so:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x+b-(1+b)}{x-1}=\ldots$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{ax^2-(1+b)}{x-1}=\ldots$$

Well, it gets even easier than what I thought as you don't even get a linear system for $\;a,b\;$ ...complete the  exercise now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find values of $a$ and $b$ so that:

1) $f$ is continuous.  I.e., $1+b=a\cdot 1^2$.

and

2) $f'$ is continuous.  I.e., $1=2\cdot a\cdot1$.